# setdate and search time

Tags: html, sorting, date, core-data, time

how i set time to date and calculate

Comment: "how i set time to date and calculate" What does that even mean?

Answer (score 4):

> But I want to be able to call a function any time during the day, and
>   it would give me the time tomorrow at exactly 07.00am, no matter when
>   I run the code.

Simply try this

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 ); //set to tomorrow's date
date.setHours( 7, 0, 0, 0 ); //set the number of hours to 7 and offset all min, sec and ms to 0
```

and get the time in milliseconds by doing

```
var ms = date.getTime();
```

Comment: OP wanted the time in milliseconds

Comment: By the way, what timezone is that by default? I need it in UTC. And then I also need it in Unix format. I think I get that by dividing the milliseconds by 1000, right?

Comment: @jeroenwiskas You can use other Date APIs to arrive at the UTC date fields https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date ..